# matplotlib graph to plot values and variance

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, variance

I am really new to the world of matplotlib graphing as well as using those graphs to understand data.

I have written a simple python code where I read a `.csv` file in and then store the values of one column into a variable. Then plotting them similar to the code bellow:

```
dev_x= X   #storing the values of the column to dev_x
plt.plot(dev_x)
plt.title('Data')
```

The graph looks like this, which seems quite messy and hard to understand. So, I am asking for some advice on how to make more cohesive graphs.

[image]

This is what my `.csv` column looks like. It is just many other other rows.

```
['40' '20' '10' '0' '10' '30' '50' '70' '90' '110' '130' '150' '170' '200'
 '240' '290' '40' '20' '10' '0' '10' '30' '50' '70' '90' '110' '130' '150'
 '170' '200' '240' '290' '40' '20' '10' '0' '10' '30' '50' '70' '90' '110'
```

At the end of the day I would like a way to display these in a better way so I can also find the variance of this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have currently stored your numbers as strings causing matplotlib to treat your variable as categorical, hence the y-axis is not ordered as expected. Before plotting you should therefore first convert them to integers like this:

```py
x = [float(i.replace(",", ".")) for i in dev_x]
```

You can then use `plt.plot(x)` once again to plot the values, this should give you the following plot:

[image]

**Edit:**

Using the csv file you've provided, I am using the following code to read in the data and create the plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Read in csv file
df = pd.read_csv("DATA.csv")
# Set figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
# Create plot
plt.plot(df["DATA"])
```

This should give the following plot:
[image]

Comment: I have tried the following order ```x = [int(i) for i in dev_x]
plt.plot(dev_x) ```   unfortunately I am getting the following error ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23,43' ```

Comment: In your example the numbers were all integers so I assumed that was the case for the rest of the numbers you didn't include as well. See my edit above, which should work for floats with a comma as the decimal point.

Comment: thank you this is where I have included your line of code ```x = [float(i.replace(",", ".")) for i in dev_x]
plt.plot(dev_x) ```   my graph is still looking the same . Here is a picture showing the results I am getting with your code and without [Picture](https://pasteboard.co/ISFg2UHw.jpg)

Comment: Can you show me the full csv file so I know what the complete data looks like?

Comment: this is a link to just the column of data that I am plotting [Link to file](https://easyupload.io/xb5uav). . Keep in mind I want to be also plotting other columns for other graph that their range of numbers might be different

Comment: Based on the data in that csv you've given me, [this](https://i.imgur.com/5LbgImF.png) is what the plot should look like.

Comment: can you please add your code of line into the existing code because I am getting a different graph and if there a way for the graph to look less crowded ?

Comment: I've added the extra code in my answer, I make the figure a little wider using `figsize=(15, 5)` to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: if there a way to fix the numbers on the Y axis because my data when I plot are filtered before plotting them so the numbers can flancuate from 1 to 1000 and then back to 35 as seen in the pictur and thus the labels on the side look not good. [photo](https://pasteboard.co/ISFEnyf.jpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103964/discussion-between-oxbowerce-and-be1995).